# runOnUIThread throwing error and crashing app

Tags: user-interface, android-runonuithread

Well I am trying to create an app but it is giving me an error:
Accessibility content change on non-UI thread. Future Android versions will throw an exception.

My java code:

```
package com.tools.cpuusage;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

//import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }

    public void refresh(View view) {
        ProgressBar p1 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        ProgressBar p2 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
        ProgressBar p3 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar3);
        ProgressBar p4 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar4);
        ProgressBar p5 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar5);
        ProgressBar p6 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar6);
        ProgressBar p7 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar7);
        ProgressBar p8 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar8);
        ProgressBar p9 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar9);
        ProgressBar p10 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar10);
        ProgressBar p11 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar11);
        ProgressBar p12 = findViewById(R.id.progressBar12);

        int accuracy = 100;

        for (int c = 0; c < 12; c++) {
            int finalC = c;
            MainActivity2.this.runOnUiThread(() -> {
                int memory = (int) ((double) accuracy * (double) ((double) ((Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() / 1024) / 1024) / (double) ((Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) / 1024)));

                if (finalC == 0) {
                    p1.setProgress(0);
                } else if (finalC == 1) {
                    p2.setProgress(78);
                } else if (finalC == 2) {
                    p3.setProgress(78);
                } else if (finalC == 3) {
                    p4.setProgress(78);
                } else if (finalC == 4) {
                    p5.setProgress(memory);
                } else if (finalC == 5) {
                    p6.setProgress(memory);
                } else if (finalC == 6) {
                    p7.setProgress(memory);
                } else if (finalC == 7) {
                    p8.setProgress(memory);
                } else if (finalC == 8) {
                    p9.setProgress(memory);
                } else if (finalC == 9) {
                    p10.setProgress(memory);
                } else if (finalC == 10) {
                    p11.setProgress(memory);
                } else {
                    p12.setProgress(memory);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {}
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar4"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar6"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/progressBar7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar7"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar8"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar7" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar9"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar8" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar10"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar9" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar11"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar10" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar12"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="369dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:progress="00"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_style"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/progressBar11" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:onClick="refresh"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar12"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,OnClick" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I inserted `runnUIThread()` in my code expecting it to be executing without the error and not crashing, but it is still giving errors and crashing.

Please help me fix them